# How to use cachetools.func tll_cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

I'm trying to keep in cache memory the return of this property that's defined inside of a class:

```
    @cached_property
    def subcommunities(self):
        return get_avatar_subcommunities(
             user_claims=self.user_claims, headers=self.headers, cookies=self.cookies, timeout=self._timeout
    )
```

Then, outside of my class I defined the function `get_avatar_subcommunities` preceded by the decorator `@ttl_cache` as follows:

```
@ttl_cache(ttl=120)
def get_avatar_subcommunities(
    user_claims: dict, headers: dict, cookies: Optional[dict], timeout: float
) -> Optional[list]:
    print('Inside of get_avatar_subcommunities')
    has_subcommunities = user_claims.get("has_subcommunities", 2)

    if has_subcommunities == 0:
        return None
    elif has_subcommunities == 1:
        return user_claims["subcommunities"]
    else:
        commuity_uuid = user_claims["community_uuid"]
        url = f"my url"
        try:
            response = HTTPHandler().get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, timeout=timeout)
            return response.json()["items"]
        except HTTPHandlerPlatformError as e:
            raise e
```

When I try to test the function, python does not even get into the function and does not print `Inside of get_avatar_subcommunities` and I get the following error:

```
sekoia/webapi/auth.py:90: in subcommunities
    return get_avatar_subcommunities(
../../../../../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachetools/func.py:56: in wrapper
    v = cache[k]
../../../../../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachetools/__init__.py:365: in __getitem__
    link = self.__getlink(key)
../../../../../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/web/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cachetools/__init__.py:495: in __getlink
    value = self.__links[key]
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = (<class 'cachetools.keys._HashedTuple'>, 'cookies', {}, 'headers', {}, 'timeout', 2.0, 'user_claims', {'community_uuid': 'foo'})
hash = <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'tuple' objects>

    def __hash__(self, hash=tuple.__hash__):
        hashvalue = self.__hashvalue
        if hashvalue is None:
>           self.__hashvalue = hashvalue = hash(self)
E           TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I don't get what the problem is, I would appreciate some help with this.
Thank you

Comment: The hash keys, i.e. the function parameters, need to be hashable for caching to work. Since dicts aren't, you cannot use them as parameters in cached functions.

Comment: exactly, I solved the problem yesterday, thank you a lot @JanWilamowski